# Cost function returns a very large value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to do a multi linear regression algorithm . My data has two features (size of the house in the first column, number of bedrooms in the second column) and here is the head of my data set (the third column is the price of the house):

```
[[2.10400e+03 3.00000e+00 3.99900e+05]
[1.60000e+03 3.00000e+00 3.29900e+05]
[2.40000e+03 3.00000e+00 3.69000e+05]
[1.41600e+03 2.00000e+00 2.32000e+05]
[3.00000e+03 4.00000e+00 5.39900e+05]]
```

I wrote the following algorithm to compute the cost :

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd  

data = np.loadtxt('data2.txt', delimiter=',')

y_data = list() 

for i in range(len(data)):
    y_data.append(data[i][2])

#Convert our list to numpy arrays 
y_data = np.asarray(y_data)

x_data = data[:, 0:2]

#applying feature scaling 
for i in range(len(x_data)):

    #Size of the house
    x_data[i][0] = (x_data[i][0] - np.mean(x_data[:, 0])) / np.std(x_data[:, 0])

    #Number of rooms 
    x_data[i][1] = (x_data[i][1] - np.mean(x_data[:, 1])) / np.std(x_data[:, 1])

#Adding a column of ones to our data
x_data = np.c_[np.ones(len(x_data)), x_data]

def cost(x, y, theta):
    m = len(x)
    predictions = np.arange(97).reshape(97, 1)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        predictions[i] = (x[i] * theta).sum()

    sqrErrors = (np.subtract(predictions, y)) ** 2
    return (1 / ( 2 * m)) * sqrErrors.sum()

theta = [[0],
         [0],
         [0]
        ]
```

The cost functions returns a value of `6361101029137.691` and when i run the gradient descent it gets larger. So what's the problem and how can i fix it please? Thanks

Comment: Check the topic called regularization, in particular, ridge regression.

Comment: Also, you need to show the optimization algorithm that you used. The problem may be there.